# Popup doesn't work in Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a *HTML* form which is a popup. When the user click the button, form will get appear at the same page.

But this code doesn't work in Wordpress post:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="OpenPopup();">
    <img border="0" src="submit.jpg">
</a>
```

What should I do for this?

Comment: form appeared without any click at the page.

Answer (score 1):

Iexplore doesn't support onClick, may be you can do this by creating a *jQuery* function :

Add *ID* first:

```
     <img id='image_id' border="0" src="submit.jpg"/>
```

Then, jQuery function:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#image_id').click(function(){
       OpenPopup();
    });
 });
 </script>
```